# IPython Jupyter Notebook Latex newpage

Tags: python, latex, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How do I insert a newpage/pagebreak into the pdf output of a Jupyter Notebook using the `IPython.display.Latex` function?

nbconvert is used:

```
nbconvert --to=pdf
```

A latex cell works fine:

```
%%latex
\newpage
```

but this doesn't do anything:

```
Latex(r"\newpage")
```

Comment: That works for me. It creates a PDF file with two pages. I don't understand what problem you had.

Comment: so it seems to work when the `Latex(r"\newpage")` is in it's own cell. But it doesn't seem work within a cell with other python code, for example: 
`Latex(r'\newpage')
print("This should be page 2")`

Comment: @ManelFornos Which is important I should mention because I'm trying to get the newpage into a for loop

Comment: @Harlekuin have you ever found a workaround to this?

Answer (score 2):

unless it's the last line of the cell (that's why it works when it's in its own cell), it should be:

```
display(Latex(r"\newpage"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Further elaborating on the answer of @Julio, what you need to incorporate some latex code into a Code cell is:

```
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex
```

then you can procedurally add Latex syntax or Math in any code cell like:

```
display(Latex(r"\newpage"))
```

for math formulas, swap `Latex` with `Math`.

This will work for scenarios where, e.g., you want to add one line break for each iteration of a for loop.